# Example of configuring Flask + AngularJS + PyJade (or other alternative to Jinja)

Tags: flask, jinja2, pyjade, webassets, flask-assets

I am new to Flask and building a web app that uses Flask and AngularJS. My understanding is that the static directory is the place to store  AngularJS files like javascript and templates.

I wonder if there is a stable alternative to Html/Jinja that I can use for templates. And if there is, how can I enable it to work with template files inside the static directory?

I was looking to PyJade but didn't get how to get it working with the web assets pipeline.

Would appreciate any example or recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mako. See [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mako/) how to install and use it. Also you could use [Genshi](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Genshi/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user3745936 I'm Syrus, creator of pyjade. What is the code you are trying to use?

Comment: Hi Syrus, I think I found an acceptable solution. I can serve AngularJS templates from the templates directory instead of the static directory, so I can run them through the jinjia pipeline and should be able to define the templates in PyJade. `@bp.route('/partials/<path:path>')
def partial(path):
    return flask.render_template('/demo/partials/{}'.format(path))`

Comment: BTW, how stable and feature complete is PyJade? Do you people using it in PROD?